# Counting numbers with $4$ distinct digits, each at most $4$

Tags: combinatorics

How many integers, greater than $999$ but not greater than $4000$, can be formed with the digits $0, 1, 2, 3$ and $4$, if repetition of digits is allowed?

Why the answer is $376$ and not $375 ? (3*5*5*5)=375$ but my book gave me answer $356$?

Comment: Do not confuse the phrase "*greater than 4000*" ($>4000$) with the phrase "*greater than* **or equal** *to 4000*" ($\geq 4000$)

Comment: I saw your all questions. You never accept any answer. You have to accept right answer so that others easily get the answer in same cases.

Answer (score 3):

The smallest number in the series is $1000,$ a $4$-digit number.

The largest number in the series is $4000$, the only $4$-digit number to start with $4$.

The left most digit (thousands place) of each of the $4$ digit numbers other than $4000$ can take one of the $3$ values: $1$ or $2$ or $3$.

The next $3$ digits (hundreds, tens and units place) can take any of the $5$ values $0$ or $1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$.

Hence, there are $3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5= 375$ numbers from $1000$ to $3999$.

Including $4000$, there will be $376$ such numbers. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

they have one of the following three formats:
1xxx
2xxx
3xxx

where x can be 0,1,2,3 or 4

each one of the three has 5^3 permutations so
(5^3) *3 = 375 I forgot to add 1 for the 4000 which makes it 376